# Al cambiar de actividad se resetean datos

Tags: java, android

Tengo una aplicación la cual contiene una tabla a la que le puedes añadir datos, como se ve en las imágenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para crear una segunda actividad tengo este codigo

```
public void metodo_anadir(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editarcontacto.class);
    intent.putExtra("DATO",3);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Meto datos en esta segunda actividad y después vuelve a la primera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al volver a darle a añadir, para añadir otro contacto, se borran los datos y vuelve a crearse la actividad de nuevo. ¿porque ocurre esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código completo de la actividad para editar datos

```
package com.example.victor.miscompaneros;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class editarcontacto extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4, campo5, campo6, campo7, campo8, advertencia1;

    Integer telefono;
    String nombre,papellido,sapellido,direccion,poblacion;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;
    ImageView foto_gallery;
    Button boton1;
    LocalDate fechanacimiento;
    TableLayout lista;

    TableRow tabla2,tabla3,tabla4,tabla5,tabla6,tabla7,tabla8,tabla9;

    int filas=0, columnas=0;

    ArrayList<Contacto> contactos= new ArrayList<Contacto>();

    int i = 0;



    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editarcontacto);

        //se asigna el campo de texto a la id que deseamos
        campo1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo1);
        campo2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo2);
        campo3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo3);
        campo4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo4);
        campo5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo5);
        campo6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo6);
        campo7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo7);
        campo8= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        foto_gallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        boton1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        lista= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.lista);

        //definimos las tablas

        tabla2= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla2);
        /*tabla3= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla3);
        tabla4= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla4);
        tabla5= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla5);
        tabla6= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla6);
        tabla7= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla7);
        tabla8= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla8);
        tabla9= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla9);

                */

        advertencia1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);



        foto_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });



        Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Le llega la accion que debe tomar
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    int dato= extras.getInt("DATO");

    if (dato==1)
    {
        campo8.setText("AÑADIR CONTACTO");
        boton1.setText("Añadir");


    }

    }

    public void metodo_iniciar(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), menucontactos.class);
        intent.putExtra("DATO",1);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    public void metodo_editar2(View view) {

        setContentView(R.layout.menucontactos);


        TextView textview1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        TextView textview2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        TextView textview3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        TextView textview4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        //se añade el contacto

        nombre=campo1.getText().toString();
        papellido=campo2.getText().toString();
        sapellido=campo3.getText().toString();
        direccion=campo4.getText().toString();
        poblacion=campo6.getText().toString();
        try {
            telefono=Integer.parseInt(campo5.getText().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){

            advertencia1.setText("INTRODUZCA UN TELEFONO CORRECTO");
            advertencia1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }try {
            fechanacimiento = LocalDate.parse(campo7.getText().toString());


            //convertimos la fecha tipo date en local date
            //fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

            LocalDate fechaactual = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(fechaactual.getYear(), fechanacimiento.getMonthValue(), fechanacimiento.getDayOfMonth());
            if (fechaactual.isAfter(birthday))
                birthday = birthday.plusYears(1);
            Period diff = Period.between(fechaactual, birthday);
            Contacto contacto = new Contacto(nombre, papellido, sapellido, direccion, poblacion, R.drawable.agenda, telefono, fechanacimiento);

            contactos.add(contacto);

            // se añade el array a la tabla del menu superior


            do {


                String n = contactos.get(i).getNombre();
                String apellido1= contactos.get(i).getPapellido();
                String apellido2= contactos.get(i).getSapellido();
                String apellidos= apellido1 +" " + apellido2;
                Integer telefono= contactos.get(i).getTelefono();
                String poblacion= contactos.get(i).getPoblacion();
                //LocalDate f = contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento();



                //añadimos los atributos a sus respectivo texto

                   textview1.setText(n);
                   textview2.setText(apellidos);
                   textview3.setText(String.valueOf(telefono));
                   textview4.setText(poblacion);

                //convertimos fecha en string para poder añadirla al texto
                //String fechatexto = contactos.get(i).convertirfecha(contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento());

                //textofecha.setText(fechatexto);



                i++;

            }while(i < (contactos.size()-1));


        }
        catch(Exception e){

            Logger.getLogger(editarcontacto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
            advertencia1.setText("INTRODUZCA UNA FECHA CORRECTA");
            advertencia1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }


    private void openGallery(){
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            foto_gallery.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Y el AndroidManifest XML(por si hiciera falta)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".menucontactos" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".editarcontacto" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: donde estas guardando los datos? son variables globales, locales al metodo?, un poco mas de info ;D

Comment: Y si los datos del pantallazo son tuyos reales, por dios! no lo pongas a la vista de todo el mundo!!

Comment: No son míos, tranquilo, voy a pasar el código de la actividad para editar datos(aunque aviso que esta incompleto y un poco desordenado)

Comment: @victor96 la respuesta es que necesitas un método de almacenamiento para guardar los datos.